# How do I make a div get a scroll bar instead of the whole page?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a chat application for mobile however I have an issue: Whenever the text-area div fills up with text instead of getting an internal scroll bar the whole page starts to get bigger pushing the text input box to the bottom of the page. I would like if the text-area had a scroll bar inside when it got too big instead of the whole webpage getting one. How do I make this happen?

```css
.text-area {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.typing-area {
  width: 95%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.messagebox {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.mega {
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>chat</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mega">
    <div class="text-area">
      <pre>LOADING!
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    </pre>
    </div>
    <form>
      <div class="typing-area">
        <input type="submit"><input type="text" class="messagebox">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you just need to give the .text-area rule a height, it should be like that.text-area{
  overflow-y:scroll;
  flex-grow: 1; height: 500px;
}

Comment: @AhmedZekry Ok, Giving it a specfic height does make it work, how can I get the height to be set based on the screen size?

Comment: Use vh for units (viewport height) rather than px.

Answer (score 0):

just throw a `height` on the `.text-area`, now the height is fixed causing an overflow:

```css
    .text-area{
      height:200px;
      overflow-y:scroll;
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
```

> snippet:

```css
.text-area{
  height:200px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.typing-area{
  width:95%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.messagebox{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.mega{
flex-direction: column;
height:100vh;
max-height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>chat</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device- 
height, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mega">
    <div class="text-area">
    <pre>LOADING!
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    helllo
    <pre>
    </div>
     <form>
    <div class="typing-area">
    <form>
    <input type="submit"><input type="text" class="messagebox">
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```